# Java Regexp. Find only one match in long text

Tags: java, regex

I need to find digits between `","` and `","`in all text.
I dont want to use `.split()` and want to do it with `regexp`.
I can easily get all matches with something like that:

```
Pattern.compile(",?(\\d+),")
```

The question is, can I get only second(or third, or forth) match?
I dont need to parse all text, I'd like to stop after N matches.
Is it possible?

Comment: Can you show examples of how your text looks like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example on how to get the 5th match:

```
    String input = "11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(",?(\\d+),");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    int counter = 0;
    int wantedMatch = 5;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        counter++;
        if (counter == wantedMatch) {
            String digits = matcher.group(1);
            System.out.println(digits); // prints 55 
            break; // stop searching after n matches.
        }
    }
    if (counter < wantedMatch) {
        System.out.println("You wanted match #" + wantedMatch + ", there only were " + counter);
    }
```

Adapt it to your needs

Comment: I completely agree with you :) Thanks for making me learn something new today. I think capturing groups could be used if you change the pattern however. But that seems overly complicated.

Comment: @jlordo Can we not simply write `if (++counter == wantedMatch)`?

Comment: @Expressions_Galore: Sure you can. IMHO, the little extra verbosity improves the readabilty a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String message = "123,456,789,101112,131415";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(",?(\\d+),");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(message);
        int i = 1;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            //Finding the second match here
            if (i == 2) {
                System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code will always return `Sorry, Not found!`, because there is no group 2 in the pattern. You need `return matcher.group(1);` and don't need the try/catch block, because there will always be the first group in a match (As you can see in the pattern).

Comment: jlordo, Thats true. I misunderstood this. Thanks now i know how it works would be editing the same soon

Comment: Also, surrounding the whole method with `try {...} catch (Exception e) {...}` just in case is pretty bad practice.

Comment: Are you trying to return the third match?

Comment: Yes, i was trying to match the second match here indeed. But since i have kept `i=0` and the counter gets updated after the match. It's obviously going to return the third match

Comment: OP says, _I'd like to stop after N matches._ Your code always parses the complete input.